# Update owl carousel items

Tags: php, jquery, html, owl-carousel

I have a carousel on a webiste, and I would like to replace all items on the fly.
(Show the results of a search function)

Currently, I'm updating the contents of the div containing the items but it breaks the carousel.
The result of the search is the html code to be placed inside the carousel.

```
<?PHP
$i = 0;
foreach ($estate as $est) {
$i++; ?>
<li>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="preview">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/uploads/ingatlan/<?php     echo $est->img ?>" alt="">
            <div class="overlay">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>ingatlan/<?php echo $est->url ?>" class="incr">
                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-thumbnail">
            <div class="telepules">
                <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                <span class="value"> <?php
                    foreach ($ingatlanadat["telep"] as $item) {
                        if ($item->id == $est->telepules)
                            echo $item->nev;
                    }
                    ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-thumbnail">
            <?php ?>
            <div class="single-thumbnail">
                <i class="icon bath"></i>
                <span class="value"><?php echo $est->bath ?></span>
            </div><?php ?>
            <div class="single-thumbnail">
                <i class="icon sleep"></i>
                <span class="value"><?php echo $est->rooms ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="single-thumbnail">
                <i class="icon corner"></i>
                <span class="value"><?php echo $est->size ?> m²</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-entry">
            <span class="item-title"><a
                    href="<?php echo base_url() ?>ingatlan/<?php echo $est->url ?>"><?php echo $est->name ?></a></span>
            <p class="text"><?php echo $est->rovid_leiras ?></p>
            <div class="item-info">
                <span class="price"><?php echo $est->price ?> Ft</span>
                <div class="pull-right buttons">
                    <b><?php
                        foreach ($ingatlanadat["tipus"] as $item) {
                            if ($item->id == $est->type)
                                echo $item->nev;
                        }
                        ?></b>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

The result of this script is passed on to this jscript, whitch is supposed to.

```
function search()
{
var form = $('form#searchform');

$.ajax({
    url: form.attr("action"),
    type: form.attr("method"),
    //dataType: 'json',
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var est = $("#estate_carousel");
        est.html(data);
        est.data('owlCarousel').destroy();
        est.init();
    }
})
```

}

What would be the proper way to do what T'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try destroying it first and then attach the newer HTML as follows:

```
var est = $("#estate_carousel");
est.data('owlCarousel').destroy();
est.html(data);
//re-init your owl carousel here again with all your required options
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined

Comment: @Frontrider - are you sure that the element id is `estate_carousel` which holds the owl carousel? Otherwise the code looks ok. this is from documentation `var owl = $(".owl-carousel").data('owlCarousel'); owl.destroy();`

Answer (score 0):

The question is pointless, after I managed to figure that the project has a different carousel under it, makes me feel a bit dumb, but whatever, I'll bookmark the answer anyways, adn I think I know where I'm going to use it.